# Facebook Graph API doesn't return next and previous pagination links

Tags: javascript, facebook, pagination

I'm trying to get all user images, but I read that facebook doesn't return all result dua to perfomance reasons.

So I read in the documentation about pagination.

But in the response I get there is no `previous` and `next` fields

My call to api:

```
FB.api(
        "/me/photos",
        function (response) {
            if (response && !response.error) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        }
    );
```

and all I get is :

```
 data: [],
 paging: cursors {
      after: "some token",
      before: "some token"
 }
```

No Previous and next links...

I would like to hear why it happen...

Thanks.

Comment: Those `cursors` are part of the pagination implementation, you can use those values to make the respective prev/next requests yourself - you just need to append them to your original query. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#paging

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that when you try to pull from `/me/photos` or from `/user-id/photos` it send only tagged photos
if you want all photos including what the user uploaded you should do

```
 /me/photos/?type=uploaded
```

Documentation

> By default reading from the photos edge includes all photos a person has been tagged in.
>   When you read a person's Photos you can also include an optional type parameter with the value uploaded to get only the list of photos that a person has uploaded: